# Please help me fix my screen resolution

Tags: display-resolution

i installed ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and the screens resolution is set at 640x480, so everything is too big.
I have gone into display settings and it will not give me and more screen resolution sizes.
I am not very good using the terminal so if anybody can help me i would greatly appreciate it :)

Im using a Asus x58c.

Comment: Please open a terminal run `lspci | grep VGA` and add the output [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/474827/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Try to install your video drivers:
You can install all video drivers with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: damo@damo-X58C:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
[sudo] password for damo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-all is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 174 not to upgrade.

Comment: thats what i got back and tried all three options with no result

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem in the first place you can try to search for a proper proprietary driver and install it.

For the following procedure you need internet access.

Go to Ubuntu Software Center > "edit" in the window panel and choose "software-sources"> select additional drivers in the window tabs> select and install a proprietary driver

Nevertheless it would be nice if you would run `lspci | grep VGA` and post the output here. Your hardware could then be possibly supported by a future kernel module.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i tried installing additional drivers through settings, but it said that there where none available.
I have tried copying and pasting a few codes to do it into the terminal but still i am having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try following goto Application Launcher Setting=>System Setting =>Display And Monitors. Here you will get current monitor. There small icon of green reload arrow. This should give you options for adjusting resolution. Following is screen shot of my Dell[image]

Comment: i do nOT HAVE THT option

Comment: Check it again.